# SQL: Get parent if and only if children have a certain property

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have an asset table with can have one or more resources in the resource table.

I want to return an asset which has ALL of the resources's status = '1', or none at all.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT id FROM asset A JOIN resource R ON A.id = R.asset_id WHERE R.status = '1'.
```

If I get a record back, how do I know this is all the resources that this asset has (i.e. it's not a subset)

(this data is fabricated and my real query is a bit more complex).

I know it's a join query, but don't know how.

Thanks for your help,

edit: title a little misleading. i mean to say ALL* children have certain property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a NOT EXISTS clause, like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM asset A 
INNER JOIN resource R ON A.id = R.asset_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     /* Only return results if the asset has resources of all status = '1'  */
     SELECT 1 
     FROM Resources R2
     WHERE A.asset_id = R2.asset_id
     AND R2.status <> '1'
)
```

Comment: +1 for `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` (Even tho in this case it is unlikely to matter)

Comment: Thank you. So easy now that I look at it. LOL!